# Is there any difference between わけにはいかない、～てはいけない and ～てはならない？

Tags: grammar, nuances

From what I understand, they all mean the same, but maybe the nuance is different or it could be something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no semantic difference between ～てはいけない and ～てはならない. They both simply mean "must not", but the latter is stiffer and more literary. The latter is naturally used in formal essays, legal documents, etc. In speech, ～てはいけない is the normal choice unless you are imitating a samurai or speaking with a serious atmosphere.

～わけにはいかない is never used to express simple "Don't" or "must not". わけ means "reason", so ～わけにはいかない is more nuanced. There is a situation-dependent "reasoning" when someone says ～わけにはいかない. It means something along the lines of "～ is not going to make sense", "～ won't do in this situation", "had better not do ～ (otherwise ...)", or "～ is not a reasonable choice (now)".